# Get Digits at the end of a String

Tags: excel

The strings are mixed alphas and digits, but there is always a set of digits at the end of the string.

Any leading digits or digits in the middle of the string should be ignored.  I came up with:

```
Public Function trailing(S As String) As Long
    Dim r As String
    Dim i As Long

    For i = Len(S) To 1 Step -1
        If IsNumeric(Mid(S, i, 1)) Then
            r = Mid(S, i, 1) & r
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    trailing = CLng(r)
End Function
```

It seems to work:

[image]

However the user is working on a *.xlsx* and can't use UDFs.  Is there a formula that gets the same results ??
Thanks in advance

Comment: Any reason why file can't be `xlsm`?

Comment: Perhaps this can help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops

Comment: @PeterB  Thanks for the reference..................but I can't use *VBA* in this case.

Comment: There's also a reference to an Excel plugin: http://seotoolsforexcel.com/regexpfind/

Comment: What is the max length of the alpha-numerics in column A? If they are short enough, you can hack together a solution with some array formulas, but it won't be pretty

Comment: @JasonAizkalns  There are 1 to 4 digits at the end of the string they will vary from **0** to **9999**

Comment: No, the actual `=len(A1)`, `=len(A2)`, etc... what's the max length? In the example, they are both 9, is it fair to say the length is a relatively small number?

Comment: This is a perfect candidate for Regex.  Too bad it requires VBA. `\d+(\.\d+)?$`

Comment: @radiocontrolled  **I agree completely**

Comment: @JasonAizkalns  The total length of the strings (including numeric suffices) varies between 12 and 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In cell B1 and copied down:

```
=--RIGHT(A1,LOOKUP(2,1/(ISNUMBER(--RIGHT(A1,ROW($1:$15)))),ROW($1:$15)))
```

Simply make sure that the 15 in `$1:$15` is going to be larger than the maximum possible number of ending digits for any given string.  No array formula entry necessary, and no helper columns necessary.

Alternate version so you don't have to repeat `ROW($1:$15)`:

```
=--RIGHT(A1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISERROR(--RIGHT(A1,ROW($1:$15))),),0)-1)
```

Comment: What does the `--` mean?

Comment: It means "Minus Negative *expression*".  Basically, it converts text to a number if it is possible to do so.  You could get the same result with `0+` or `1*`. I just like how `--` looks.

Comment: Wow this is really clever!

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so bear with me...this is ugly and there could be some opportunity to clean this up (or a better approach altogether utilizing the same concepts) and since you already know that this is a much better candidate for RegEx/VBA, we are in agreement of a better approach, yet under the criteria/restrictions of your question, here we go...

Since you said the length varies between 2 and 12, we can make a set of array formulas in 12 columns, `B-M` which extracts the `RIGHT()` of 1, 2, ..., 12 characters accordingly. We wrap this with a `VALUE` to return an error `#VALUE!` for non-numerics -- NOTE: This formula is entered by first selecting cells `B2:M2`, typing the formula, `=VALUE(RIGHT(A2, {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}))` and then the obligatory <kbd>CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER</kbd>

We then find the position of the first error in `COLUMN O` with a `MATCH()` formula looking for the first `TRUE` of another array formula utilizing `ISERROR()`.

We get the solution by doing an index of the position 1-12 columns returning the column next to the first error it finds. This is because you know that column A will always end in a number.

**N.B. Since you specified that it is only a 4-digit numeric string at the end, you can probably get away with reducing this method to the first 4 columns; that is, rather than utilizing 12 columns, just use columns `B:E` and continue as above.**

[image: Excel]

We end by begging the client/customer to consider a `.xlsm` workbook/VBA/RegEx or other solution...

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,--RIGHT(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)))),1)
```

In some cases it could give wrong results:

`aaa12.1`
`bc1E+13`

As a workaround you can use `SUBSTITUTE` to replace `E`, `e` and `.` (maybe also `,` and space) in input string with another letter.

Comment: Thanks....................I will check if my user's version of Excel will support *Aggregate()*